# C++ non-blocking send/recv work only on one side(client or server)

Tags: c++, sockets, client-server, nonblocking

I'm implementing a server in C++ with non-blocking sockets.

Since I want to send messages between the client & server, I wrote 2 wrappers around send/recv syscalls. Mainly, I want to prepend 4Bytes (message length) to every message, so that the receiver knows how long to execute recv.

Moreover I have a client/server programs that each start a socket and listen on localhost.
Then the client sends a random message, which the server receives.

When I try,however, to send from the server to the client, both programs halt.

I have tested the wrappers many times and they read/deliver data, but whenever I try to receive on a previously sending connection, then comes the problem.

I know that there is a memory leak in the `secure_recv` but I need it to pass some custom tests, which are not very well written.

The issue lies in the select, which returns a positive number, but then I never go inside the  `if (FD_ISSET(fd, &readset))` statement.

What am I doing wrong and how can we fix it ? Thanks a lot !

**EDIT**
My problem was that the sockets were blocking(busy working) at the select function. I updated the code so that there is no select in the secure_* functions. It's a much better way to first check if the socket is available for send/recv on a client/server thread level via select and then calling the secure_* functions. Question is answered for now.

**client.cpp**

```
// Client side C/C++ program to demonstrate Socket programming
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "util.h"
#define PORT 8080

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int sock = 0, valread;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
    {
        printf("\n Socket creation error \n");
        return -1;
    }

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    // Convert IPv4 and IPv6 addresses from text to binary form
    if (inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &serv_addr.sin_addr) <= 0)
    {
        printf("\nInvalid address/ Address not supported \n");
        return -1;
    }

    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
    {
        printf("\nConnection Failed \n");
        return -1;
    }

    int numbytes;
    size_t size = 0;
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> buf = get_rand_data(size);
    if ((numbytes = secure_send(sock, buf.get(), size, 0)) == -1)
    {
        std::cout << std::strerror(errno) << "\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    std::cout << "Client sent : " << numbytes << "\n";

    int64_t bytecount = -1;
    while (1)
    {
        std::unique_ptr<char[]> buffer;
        if ((bytecount = secure_recv(sock, buffer, 0)) <= 0)
        {
            if (bytecount == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        std::cout << bytecount << "\n";
    }

    std::cout << "Client received : " << bytecount << "\n";

    close(sock);

    return 0;
}
```

**server.cpp**

```
// Server side C/C++ program to demonstrate Socket programming
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "util.h"

#define PORT 8080
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int server_fd, new_socket, valread;
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    int opt = 1;
    int addrlen = sizeof(address);
    
    // Creating socket file descriptor
    if ((server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == 0)
    {
        perror("socket failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    // Forcefully attaching socket to the port 8080
    if (setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT,
                                                &opt, sizeof(opt)))
    {
        perror("setsockopt");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    address.sin_port = htons( PORT );
    
    // Forcefully attaching socket to the port 8080
    if (bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address,
                                sizeof(address))<0)
    {
        perror("bind failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (listen(server_fd, 3) < 0)
    {
        perror("listen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if ((new_socket = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address,
                    (socklen_t*)&addrlen))<0)
    {
        perror("accept");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
     // set the socket to non-blocking mode
    fcntl(new_socket, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);


    int64_t bytecount = -1;
    while (1) {
        std::unique_ptr<char[]> buffer;
        if ((bytecount = secure_recv(new_socket, buffer, 0))  <= 0) {
            if (bytecount == 0) {
                    break;
            }
        }
        std::cout << bytecount << "\n";
    }



    int numbytes;
    size_t size = 0;
    std::unique_ptr<char[]> buf = get_rand_data(size);
    if ((numbytes = secure_send(new_socket, buf.get(), size, 0)) == -1)
    {
        std::cout << std::strerror(errno) << "\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    std::cout << "Client sent : " << numbytes << "\n";


    close(new_socket);

    return 0;
}
```

**util.h**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <algorithm>
#include <memory>
#include <poll.h>
#include <iomanip>

/**
 * It takes as arguments one char[] array of 4 or bigger size and an integer.
 * It converts the integer into a byte array.
 */
void convertIntToByteArray(char *dst, int sz)
{
    auto tmp = dst;
    tmp[0] = (sz >> 24) & 0xFF;
    tmp[1] = (sz >> 16) & 0xFF;
    tmp[2] = (sz >> 8) & 0xFF;
    tmp[3] = sz & 0xFF;
}

/**
 * It takes as an argument a ptr to an array of size 4 or bigger and 
 * converts the char array into an integer.
 */
int convertByteArrayToInt(char *b)
{
    return (b[0] << 24) + ((b[1] & 0xFF) << 16) + ((b[2] & 0xFF) << 8) + (b[3] & 0xFF);
}

/**
 * It constructs the message to be sent. 
 * It takes as arguments a destination char ptr, the payload (data to be sent)
 * and the payload size.
 * It returns the expected message format at dst ptr;
 *
 *  |<---msg size (4 bytes)--->|<---payload (msg size bytes)--->|
 *
 *
 */
void construct_message(char *dst, char *payload, size_t payload_size)
{
    convertIntToByteArray(dst, payload_size);

    memcpy(dst + 4, payload, payload_size);
}

/**
 * It returns the actual size of msg.
 * Not that msg might not contain all payload data. 
 * The function expects at least that the msg contains the first 4 bytes that
 * indicate the actual size of the payload.
 */
int get_payload_size(char *msg, size_t bytes)
{
    // TODO:
    return convertByteArrayToInt(msg);
}

/**
 * Sends to the connection defined by the fd, a message with a payload (data) of size len bytes.
 * The fd should be non-blocking socket.
 */

/**
 * Receives a message from the fd (non-blocking) and stores it in buf.
 */
int secure_recv(int fd, std::unique_ptr<char[]> &buf)
{
    // TODO:
    int valread = 0;
    int len = 0;
    int _len = 4;
    bool once_received = false;

    std::vector<char> ptr(4);

    while (_len > 0)
    {

        int _valread = recv(fd, ptr.data() + valread, _len, MSG_DONTWAIT);

        if (_valread == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        if (_valread > 0)
        {
            _len -= _valread;
            valread += _valread;
        }

        if (!once_received && valread == 4)
        {

            once_received = true;

            len = convertByteArrayToInt(ptr.data());

            _len = len;

            ptr = std::vector<char>(len);

            valread = 0;
        }
    }

    buf = std::make_unique<char[]>(len);

    memcpy(buf.get(), ptr.data(), len);

    return len;
}

/**
 * Sends to the connection defined by the fd, a message with a payload (data) of size len bytes.
 * The fd should be non-blocking socket.
 */
int secure_send(int fd, char *data, size_t len)
{
    // TODO:

    char ptr[len + 4];
    int valsent = 0;
    int _len = 4;
    bool once_sent = false;

    construct_message(ptr, data, len);

    while (_len > 0)
    {

        int _valsent = send(fd, ptr + valsent, _len, MSG_DONTWAIT);

        if (_valsent == 0)
        {
            break;
        }

        if (_valsent > 0)
        {
            _len -= _valsent;
            valsent += _valsent;
        }

        if (!once_sent && valsent == 4)
        {

            once_sent = true;

            _len = len;
        }
    }

    return len;
}
```

**Compilation via**

```
g++ -O3 -std=c++17 -Wall -g -I../ client.cpp -o client -lpthread
```

Comment: The code is not sufficiently documented so it is hard to compare what you intend to what you actually do. But I see multiple problems here: you don't check if you fully send or received the data in your secure_* functions but just rely on send/recv causing errors if the given length is 0. You blindly assume that you will receive 4 bytes length inside a single read even though recv is not guaranteed to do this. Also you don't have any debug output to see what's actually going on and where it blocks and why.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. You hit the nail on the head. How can I verify that I've received 4 bytes ? While loop until i've read 4 Bytes which is the message length and then recv  the message body with non-blocking flag MSG_DONTWAIT ? I'm still not sure if i need the select function. secure_* functions are called by threads who each have multiple socket connections. Should I handle that select logic before calling secure_* ? Thanks

Comment: *How can I verify that I've received 4 bytes* - check the return value of `recv`. *"I'm still not sure if i need the select function."* - you basically implement blocking behavior on a single socket yourself. `select` is useful if you want to handle multiple events (i.e. multiple sockets, timeouts, read or write ...) but is overkill just for expecting a single event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with the write loop:

```
while (1)
{

    // std::cerr << "first iteration send\n";

    FD_ZERO(&writeset);
    FD_SET(fd, &writeset);

    if (select(fd + 1, NULL, &writeset, NULL, NULL) > 0)
    {

        if (FD_ISSET(fd, &writeset))
        {
            valsent = send(fd, ptr + valsent, _len, 0);
```

Oops. This loses `valsent`, which tracks how many bytes you've sent so far. So on your third loop, `ptr + valsent` will only add the number of bytes received the second time. You need to track the total number of bytes sent so far somewhere.

```
            if (valsent <= 0)
            {
                break;
            }

            _len -= valsent;
```

And what if `_len` becomes zero? You'll still call `select` and even `send`. You probably want that `while (1)` to be `while (_len > 0)`.

```
        }
    }
}
return len;
```

Now, onto the read loop:

```
    if (select(fd + 1, &readset, NULL, NULL, NULL) > 0)
    {

        if (FD_ISSET(fd, &readset))
        {

            if (first_iteration)
            {
                recv(fd, ptr, 4, 0);
```

You ignore the return value of `recv` here. What if it's not 4?

```
                len = convertByteArrayToInt(ptr);

                buf = std::make_unique<char[]>(len);

                _len = len;
                first_iteration = false;
            }

            valread = recv(fd, buf.get() + valread, _len, 0);

            if (valread <= 0)
            {
                break;
            }

            _len -= valread;
```

You don't leave the loop if `_len` is zero. You'll call `select` again, waiting for data that may never come.

```
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, I solved my issues by removing the select function from both secure_* functions. Since I'm building a client-server application it was a mistake to wait for the sockets inside these functions. I should've thought this through in a better way. But now both are non-blocking and I updated the code above. Maybe check it out if you wish, but for now my question is answered.